# What is the script in javascript equals to $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] in php?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to know the filename from where a javascript function has been called.
example.

I have a php file Test.php. In test.php file I am calling a whocalled(); javascipt function.

Now how to get test.php filename in whocalled(); function.
The whocalled(); function is called from many php file and i want to know the php filename and based on that another code is being called.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is run on the server side, thus JavaScript running in the browser has no native way to grab this variable.

What you could do in your test PHP file is output this value to a JS variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var scriptFilename = '<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ?>';
</script>
```

However! This is dangerous and could potentially show details of your server that you are not wanting to show to an attacker. I am merely showing you how to get a variable from PHP so that JavaScript can see the value.

Comment: This does not serve my purpose as you only gave me the reason. I just want the filename without getting displayed. else i could have passed it in the function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
<script>
  var script_filename = window.location.pathname;
 </script>
```

Comment: This give me the URL address. If i have embedded the file in iframe then above code will not give correct filename.